# How can I do this type of loop by python?

Tags: python, loops

I am learning basic Python. I want to make a program whose workflow is:

> A= *Users will input integer value*
> B= *Users will input integer value*

> How many times do you want to do the task?/Task Count = *Users will input integer value*

And then it will do some task like this:

> task1=A+B & print task1

> task2=A*B & print task2

> task3=A-B & print task3

When every task will complete it will repeat from task1 until the 'task count' is equal.[][1]

> ```
>          .
>          .
>          .
>          .
> ```
>
> Will continue to do so

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: let it slide.it is not working

Comment: what did you try? where is your code? Show it even if it doesn't work. If it gives error message then show full error message. If it gives wrong results then show wrong results and expected results.

Comment: sorry i have deleted my source.I wont do so next time. thanks a lot. "patate1684" gave me right solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
A = int(input("Enter first integer: "))
B = int(input("Enter second integer: "))

n = int(input("how many time ? "))

for i in range(n):
    task1 = A+B
    print(task1)
    task2 = A*B
    print(task2)
    task3 = A-B
    print(task3)
```